# Error:(35) Error: Version must be at least 10.2.1 when targeting O [GradleCompatible]

Tags: android

My build gradle file, i am getting the above error on trying to build signed apk, which version is this error talking about?

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.0.+'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.4.0'
```

Comment: Firebase is the only target for the solution, change 9.4.0 to 10.2.1

Answer (score 0):

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.4.0'
```

Replace this line with the following line

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.4'
```

Comment: Note: you can find out what the latest version of the plugin is here ("Cloud Messaging").
 https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#latest_sdk_versions